# Function does not raise error with incorrect input

Tags: r, string, compare

Here is my [script](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/blob/master/R/RanglaPunjab.R) in GitHub [repo](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/).

It works with `ListPalette()` and `ListPalette("PunjabiPalette")`

If I pass in an incorrect value, instead of displaying an error and terminating the function, it goes ahead and displays the palette.

I also tried `listname != "PunjabiPalette"` and `!identical(listname,"PunjabiPalette")`

How can I correctly show an error if the argument is not correct?

```
ListPalette <- function(listname){

  if (is.null(names(args))){
    listname <- "PunjabiPalette"
  }
  else if (!(args  %in% "PunjabiPalette")){
    stop(paste0(listname, " does not exist."))
  }

  list <- get(listname)
  names(list)
}
```

Comment: What is `args`?

Comment: `args` is arguments passed into function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args()` is a default function that can get the arguments of an already defined function, it doesn't let you access the arguments inside a function definition. So your approach as is won't work.

Your first `if` statement is not necessary, you can specify default arguments in R by including them with an `=` in the function definition. To stop on an invalid input, using `listname != "PunjabiPalette"` works fine for me, as shown below. The function correctly errors on an input that isn't `"PunjabiPalette"`. I am assuming also that you have defined it as a list in the global environment, given the use of `get`. I wouldn't recommend this practice (try making a list of lists) but this should hopefully work for the time being.

```r
PunjabiPalette <- list("a" = 1, "b" = 2) # example list with named elements
ListPalette <- function(listname = "PunjabiPalette"){

  if (listname != "PunjabiPalette"){
    stop(paste0(listname, " does not exist."))
  }

  list <- get(listname)
  names(list)
}

print(ListPalette()) # works with missing argument
#> [1] "a" "b"
print(ListPalette("PunjabiPalette")) # works with valid argument
#> [1] "a" "b"
print(ListPalette("OtherName")) # fails with incorrect argument
#> Error in ListPalette("OtherName"): OtherName does not exist.
```

Created on 2018-05-30 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).